# Nested css selectors by adding to class name in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, flexbox

I am building a flexbox grid system and am looking to keep my scss file manageable.

What is wrong with the selectors for elements with classes *col-2, col-4, col-6* that are causing them not to work?

```
.grid-container{
max-width:1280;
margin: 0 24px;
display: flex;

    [class^="col"]{
        flex:1;
        margin: 0 8px;

        &:first-child{
            margin-left:0;
        }
        &:last-child{
           margin-right:0;
        }

        [class*="-2"]{
            width:16.5%;
        }

        [class*="-4"]{
            width:33%;
        }

        [class*="-6"]{
            width:50%;
        }
    }
}
```

All columns are getting the styling for margin and the first-child and last-child behavior but not the width from the other selectors. Is this perhaps a flexbox issue? flex-basis?

Comment: Try `&[class*="-2"]` (note the `&`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[class^="col"] {
  [class*="-2"] {
    width: 16.5%;
  }
  [class*="-4"] {
    width: 33%;
  }
  [class*="-6"] {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Will produce the following selectors:

```
[class^="col"] [class*="-2"] {}
[class^="col"] [class*="-4"] {}
[class^="col"] [class*="-6"] {}
```

Notice the space between each attribute selector. The selectors above will first search for and element that has a class attribute that starts with the `.col` class. They then find an element nested within the `.col` element with a class attribute that contains `-2`, `-4` or `-6` somewhere in the attribute.

By adding an ampersand `&` you can capture the current selector path. The following SCSS is the same as what you have now:

```
[class^="col"] {
  & [class*="-2"] {
    width: 16.5%;
  }
}
```

Compiles to (space between attribute selectors):

```
[class^="col"] [class*="-2"] {}
```

Placing the ampersand immediately before the nested selector (like you have with `first-child` and `last-child`) gives a different result, the one you (likely) want:

```
[class^="col"] {
  &[class*="-2"] {
    width: 16.5%;
  }
}
```

Compiles to (no space between attribute selectors):

```
[class^="col"][class*="-2"] {}
```

---

IMHO what you have currently is over engineered. I'd suggest something more straightforward and flexible. Use regular class selectors.

```
.col {    
  &-2 { width: 16.5%; }
  &-4 { width: 33%; }
  &-6 { width: 50%; }    
}

[class*="col-"] {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 8px;

  &:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
  &:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
}
```

See below Stack Snippet to see what the above is compiled to. Note that I used `*=` (asterisk equals) instead of `^=` (caret equals) for class placement flexibility. Up to you if you want to enforce column classes to be the first class in the class attribute value.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXveRq

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-2 { width: 16.5%; }
.col-4 { width: 33%; }
.col-6 { width: 50%; }

[class*="col-"] {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

[class*="col-"]:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
[class*="col-"]:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-4">Col 2</div>
  <div class="col-4">Col 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a "flexbox" issue. It's a "CSS" issue.

```css
[class^="col"] {
   [class*="-2"] {
       width:16.5%;
   }
}
```

will result in this CSS:

```
[class^="col"] [class*="-2"]{width:16.5%;}
```

But you probably want...

```
[class^="col"][class*="-2"]{width:16.5%;}
```

... which would be produced by...

```css
[class^="col"] {
   &[class*="-2"] {
       width:16.5%;
   }
}
```

The space  (in CSS) and the ampersand `&` (in SCSS) are the differences.

Answer (score 0):

CoJanks.
The quick and dirt fix is to set additional definitions to the 'flex' on the **.col** class in the .grid-container.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisallen/o1zgk4za/10/) is a quick and dirty answer to solve your problem for ya!

`flex:1 1 auto;`

FYI. There were some discrepancies in class nesting as well that I covered in the link provided.